# Extract year from parameter in dbt

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am trying to extract to year, month , day from passed parameters in macros written in jinja.
The passed input_date is string
Below is my code

```
{% macro extract_year(input_date)%}
    Select date_part('year', CAST( {{ input_date }} as Date))
{% endmacro %}
```

Also tried

```
{% macro extract_year(input_date)%}
    MONTH(CAST({{ input_date }} as DATE))
{% endmacro %}
```

But I am getting an error
So the cast itself is not working here
`Cast ' ' is invalid`

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is. Are you getting errors? Are you not getting the right output? Whatever it is--it needs to be part of the question

Comment: Apologies, editted

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the format of the input date being passed in. If it's a str you could try putting quotes around the `{{ input_date }}`

So it becomes:

```
{% macro extract_year(input_date)%}
    Select date_part('year', CAST('{{ input_date }}' as Date))
{% endmacro %}
```

You might also need to specify the format of the date str being passed in